# RPI3 and SIM800 - How to connect

Tags: pi-3

I need some help. I'm absolute new in the topic raspberry pi.
I'm trying to connect the RPI3 with the SIM800 (https://www.itead.cc/wiki/RPI_SIM800_GSM/GPRS_ADD-ON_V2.0).

What I did:

- Connected the Raspberry with GSM Module Sim800 over the serials pins
  directly.
- Bought a new sim to send sms
- I already tried some comments from the post:[Connect sim800 to Raspberry PI (RX, TX)](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/64270/connect-sim800-to-raspberry-pi-rx-tx)

Whats my problem:
If I try to run the code

```
import serial   
import os, time

# Enable Serial Communication
port = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyS0', baudrate=9600, timeout=1)

# Transmitting AT Commands to the Modem
# '\r\n' indicates the Enter key

port.write('AT'+'\r\n')
rcv = port.read(10)
print rcv
```

I get a empty response. I also need to say that my Sim800 is searching for a network(according to the blinking LED)

Hopefully some of you can help me out with my problem.

Regards,
Burner

Comment: Have you tried connecting via `minicom` or `miniterm.py`?  The latter is more minimal but is less grumpy?

Comment: According to the minicom statusbar (on the bottom of the window) it says following:CTRL-A Z for help | 9600 8N1 | NOR | Minicom 2.7 | VT102 | Offline | ttyS0

Comment: Yes, minicom is like that.  I've found it useless when miniterm.py works with the exact same settings on various things including a SIM900.  It comes packaged with pyserial so you will already have it installed.

Comment: i used to connect it over miniterm.py but after connecting  to dev/ttyS0. I can't send any commands, but i can open the menu. I had the same problem with minicom.