# How to connect GSM module to Raspberry PI3 and also using Bluetooth of Raspberry PI3

Tags: pi-3, serial, internet, gsm

I want to use Bluetooth of Raspberry Pi3 and also I want to Connect GSM module sim800l to Raspberry Pi3 ,in [this instruction](https://www.modmypi.com/blog/how-to-connect-your-raspberry-pi-to-a-3g-network)
 Bluetooth will be disable , what is the the best way to use both of them?

From [this link](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/64270/connect-sim800-to-raspberry-pi-rx-tx) I add `enable_uart=1` in `/boot/config.txt` 
and I did this:

```
sudo apt-get install ppp
sudo wget "https://www.modmypi.com/download/sakis3g.tar.gz" -O sakis3g.tar.gz
sudo tar -xzvf sakis3g.tar.gz
sudo chmod +x sakis3g
sudo nano /etc/sakis3g.conf
```

in **sakis3g.conf** I added this :

```
CUSTOM_TTY="/dev/ttyS0"
BAUD=9600
APN=CUSTOM_APN
CUSTOM_APN=”sim apn”
```

I run `sudo ./sakis3g ----interactive connect` 
the ouput is

**Modem unable to register a network.**

**connection failed**

The sim doesn't have password 
So why the module cannot connect to internet?

Answer (score 0):

The tutorial you linked uses `rpi-update`

> "In normal circumstances there is NEVER a need to run rpi-update as it always gets you to the leading edge firmware and kernel and because that may be a testing version it could leave your RPi unbootable". https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?p=916911#p916911
>   Even the [rpi-update](https://github.com/Hexxeh/rpi-update) documentation now warns "Even on Raspbian you should only use this with a good reason. This gets you the latest bleeding edge kernel/firmware."

`sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get install --reinstall raspberrypi-bootloader raspberrypi-kernel`
will put it back to the latest supported kernel/bootcode.

There is **NO reason** to disable Bluetooth.

To use serial use `dev/serial0` see [How do I make serial work on the Raspberry Pi3 , Pi3B+, PiZeroW](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/45571/8697)

Comment: I did what you said, enable serial port and disable serial console, but after restart pi3  both of them is enable why? 
and I edit `CUSTOM_TTY="/dev/ttyS0"` to `CUSTOM_TTY="/dev/serial0"` in sakis3.conf. when I run
`sudo ./sakis3g ----interactive connect` sometimes output is **Modem unable to register a network.**
and sometimes  **in step connecting ,show connected fail** why it not connect to network?

Comment: This was due to the power supply, if the module is fed properly, it can be connected to the Internet, it should feed 4.2 volts with 2A